# WearableListView setEnableGestureNavigation not available

Tags: android, android-support-library, wear-os

I am developing my Android Wear app and I can't use `setEnableGestureNavigation`

I am using a `WearableListView` from `com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0`

I can use any method of WearableListView but setEnableGestureNavigation() which is not available. However, it can be found in the docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WearableListView.html?hl=es#setEnableGestureNavigation(boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, `setEnableGestureNavigation` has been released in `com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0`

Answer (score -2):

As you can see in the documentation, you have to use `setEnableGestureNavigation` with a `boolean` parameter:

```
void setEnableGestureNavigation (boolean enabled)
```

Try using a parameter will resolve the problem.

Comment: The original poster knows that already, since they posted a link to the JavaDoc.